# Calling C++ class from NSIS

Tags: c++, nsis

I just want to know if there is any way to call a c++ class into our nsis script ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS can call functions in DLLs but the calling convention is somewhat limited and there's no direct support for classes. You will not be able to easily call class function.

You might be able to "hack" it by making `extern "C"` wrapper functions for every class member function, along with function that create and destroy instances of the class as necessary. You'd have to somehow passes something that represents the newly created instances back to NSIS, which then would pass it into the wrapper functions along with any necessary parameters/arguments.

Sounds like more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: Yeah, sounds troublesome. Imma find some other way then. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the easiest way to call your function will be to export it to dll and then call them from nsis using `System::Call` function.